# Warnings of valid HTML5 attributes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html

I use Eclipse and I write jsp files with HTML5 content.
So I have for example this line:

```
<div class="test" data-role="test123">
```

In Eclipse I get the warning:

> ```
> Undefined attribute name (data-role)
> ```

What needed to be done so these warnings won't appear anymore? In HTML5 this attribute is allowed (`data-*`) as you can see here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Does Eclipse support HTML5 ? I'm using the last NetBeans .. and it doesn't support it yet..

Comment: It should. See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292415
@OP Is your Eclipse/WTP etc. up to date?

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.5.2. / WTP 3.1.1. which is bundled with Spring. So an update to 3.6.1. will remove these warnings?

Comment: Can't promise, have never tried. I suggest you install the Eclipse WTP Helios package separately and test it out (should be quick). If it works you can upgrade your production environment.

Comment: Well, Eclipse doesn't require any installation. You basically just extract the archive to a different location and run the executable there :)
You can then point to the same workspace (or copy your workspace beforehand) to test your file in question.

Comment: You also want to be sure to have the correct DOCTYPE declared at the top of the file.

Comment: Eclipse still (4.2.2) incorrectly warns about the 'role' attribute of html5 code.

Answer (score 37):

It seems like Eclipse still has some problems validating HTML5 elements and attributes even now.

I'm running Mars 4.5.1 and I have had warnings about the `<main>` element, despite the fact that there are no warnings about the `<section>` element.

But there is a solution!

```
Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Validation
```

[image: Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Validation]

Here you can tick the `Ignore specified element names in validation` checkbox and enter the names of any elements which Eclipse is incorrectly warning you about.

In your case, you will want to tick the `Ignore specified attribute names in validation` checkbox and enter the `data-role` attribute.

After you click 'Apply', Eclipse will ask you to do a full validation of the project. Select 'Yes' and the changes will take effect.

No more squiggly yellow lines YAY! :D

Comment: Though I do want a validation of my file. I want eclipse to warn me, so I want it to know it's part of the HTML5 spec. I'm sure in 2016 there is a way for Eclipse to learn HTML5.

Comment: I am using `Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500` with 10 plugins, installed on `Microsoft Windows Creators' Update [Version 10.0.15063]`. My HTML5 element is `<option>` and my HTML5 attributes are `mytag`, `myproduct`, `gstitemprice` and `mygstcat`. Using your solution, I have got rid of four warnings, after Eclipse has performed a full XML validation on the whole workspace. I wonder though whether I am doing the right thing.

Comment: Hi in my eclipse mars 2 i am not able see these options. can you please suggest some other methods ??

Comment: Reading this answer I realized the question was not about fixing eclipse but about not to see the errors... :-(

Comment: This is not really a fix for me. When I tell eclipse to ignore <main>, it still complains about invalid attributes "role" and "class" inside <main>. I don't want to disable validation of frequently used attributes such as "class". If there was a way to specify attributes only when appearing in certain tags, I would use it.

Answer (score 23):

Your doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

is for HTML 4.01.

`data-*` attributes were added in HTML 5. The doctype for HTML 5 is basically either

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Newer versions of Eclipse support HTML5 tags and the data-* attributes allowed in HTML5. However, when using the role attribute the proper syntax according to the [ARIA Roles Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) and [XHTML Role Attribute Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/) is **not to prefix the role attribute with data-*** leaving just role and not data-role.

So `<ul role="menubar">` is more correct than `<ul data-role="menubar">`. The validity of the syntax can be checked using the [(X)HTML5 Validator](http://html5.validator.nu/). jQuery Mobile uses quite extensively the data-role attribute, though I'm not sure why.

**Note:** If you upgrade and you're still getting warnings on data-* attributes you may want to consider updating or removing any installed syntax-checkers such as JTidy. As of Indigo Service Release 1 the role attribute continues to trigger an undefined attribute warning in Eclipse by default.

Comment: I can’t support the statement that *"Newer versions of Eclipse support HTML5 tags"*. I get stuff like `Unknown tag (main)` with a fresh installation.

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse in a few years @kleinfreund, but perhaps this post I wrote around the time I gave this answer will still help you: https://habd.as/get-sideways-with-html5-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 4):

I used this one with Aptana 3.6 when I'am coding AngularJS

> Window > Preferences

[image: Choose Ignore Proprietary Attributes]

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Aptana Studio plugin](http://aptana.org/products/studio3) on Mac OS X; if I go `Eclipse > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML`, and create the filter `*data-role*` I no longer get this warning.

I believe on Windows it is `Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML`

[image: Aptana HTML Validation]

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 3.6 introduced a new field under:

`Validation -> HTML Syntax: Ignore specified attribute names in validation`

Add the OpenGraph, RDFa or other non-HTML5 attributes you want the validator to ignore:

[image: Ignore specified attribute names in validation]

You will need to re-validate the project, then the warnings will be gone.

Comment: **"or other non-HTML5 attributes"** The problem is that Eclipse warns about attributes that *are* in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse observes the DOCTYPE declaration. In my case, the solution was using the code above at the first line of the files containing HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Related to that, there's this other question, already answered:

[Why do we need DOCTYPE to the HTML/JSP pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147799/why-do-we-need-doctype-to-the-html-jsp-pages)