# How can I add custom html attribut description for Aptana?

Tags: html, angularjs, aptana

I am working with a javascript Framework that wants custom attributs in the HTML... And Aptana shows this as invalid (underlined) with no description.. I'd like to add some of these, is it possible?

Comment: I don't know Aptana but you should prefix [custom attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) with the prefix **data-** as such **data-my-attribute** to avoid future collisions.

Comment: I have no control over that, I'm using Angular which renders my templates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefix AngularJS attributes and also directives with `data-` and they will stil work. For example:

```
<body data-ng-app="app" >
    <div data-ng-controller="TestController">
        <span test-directive>
            {{test}}     
        </span>                        
    </div>        
</body>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDKVC/5/) to check this out.

Think that way Aptana will treat attributes as valid but you'll have to verify that.

---

To manually add atributes, please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917925/617996).

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix to just stop the editor from displaying attribute warnings that I did was:
Go to Windows > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy Validator > Attributes.
Then set 'Proprietary Attributes' to ignore.