# "Unknown tag (main)" warning in JSP file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, jsp, tags

I have this annoying behaviour with Eclipse where it warns me about the `<main>` element in my JSP file.

I've got `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my page and I'm using several other HTML5 elements, such as `<header>` and `<footer>`, but Eclipse doesn't give a warning about these.

I tried switching off HTML and JSP syntax validation but that didn't seem to work.

I just don't understand why it has a problem with the `<main>` tag but not other HTML5 tags and that little yellow underline is SUPER irritating.

How can I get Eclipse to ignore this tag?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193905/warnings-of-valid-html5-attributes-in-eclipse

Comment: Thank you very much! I discovered that my version of Eclipse does actually allow you to ignore a specific element that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it seems like people were having a similar problem with HTML5 attributes according to the question linked in the comment @safin chacko.

The answers posted there show how you could get Eclipse to ignore validation of specified *attributes*. Since then it seems that Eclipse has the added feature of being able to also ignore validation of specified *elements*

[I have posted an answer on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35436091/5620549) which also answers my own question.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a Bugzilla item for this already. Hopefully, when that is addressed, the problem will go away.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516758

In the meantime, you can suppress the warning by going to Eclipse > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Validation and adding main to the comma-separated list element names to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause for this warning might be you are using footer tag without a header tag.

1.Create a separate file say  "Footer.html" and write your footer content in that.

2.Include that footer.html in your main .jsp file through :
**<%@ include file="Footer.html"%>**

You can try the same for header also.