# Is there a way to get Aptana to recognize <main>?

Tags: html, editor, program-entry-point, aptana

I am learning web design with Aptana and I have ran into a weird problem. The HTML editor does not recognize main element. Therefore, my .css file cannot select main element to style it. I have checked under windows --> preferences --> general --> editors and have made sure the HTML editor is default and selected. The only others are two text editors and web browser. Any fixes to this? Is it possible to download a better editor and install into Aptana? It has an add button.

Comment: I changed it to section and it fixed it. However, I do like using main for semantic reasons so if anybody has a fix let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this element is not recognized because it is relatively new: at this time, it is not yet supported by the HTML Editor in [Eclipse Web Tools](https://eclipse.org/webtools/) for Neon.3, as you can see on [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516758) for example).

You can also see these other related questions:

- [HTML5 Pass-Through element causes Eclipse warning 'Unknown tag'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34016167/)
- ["Unknown tag (main)" warning in JSP file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35433161/)
- [Warnings of valid HTML5 attributes in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4193905/)