# Eclipse - Undefined attribute name Warning

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm trying to use avalonjs([on github](https://github.com/RubyLouvre/avalon)) in eclipse . I add dependency in my login.html at `<head>` tag like this`<script src="${root!}/assets/avalon/avalon.min.js"></script>` . I can get back end's data from `ms-click="ldCode"` . it get some validate code from back end.but eclipse give an warning **Undefined attribute name (ms-click).** and all avalon attributes get this warning.Is this a problem? 
 Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warnings of valid HTML5 attributes in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193905/warnings-of-valid-html5-attributes-in-eclipse)

Comment: @FaizMohamedHaneef - It's close, but that question is about a *valid* attribute (it has a `data-` prefix), and the top answer is that newer versions of Eclipse have been updated to understand `data-` attributes. The attributes ued by Avalon are not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a problem?

Only if you want your HTML to be strictly valid (e.g., to pass [validation](http://validator.w3.org/)). There is no `ms-click` attribute defined in the HTML specification; one is [supposed to use a `data-` prefix](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) on all non-standard attributes.

But many libraries violate that rule. It's only a problem if there's a conflict (two libs using the same name for different things) or HTML itself gets a conflicting attribute. But the rule is there, which is why Eclipse is warning you about those attributes.

Comment: I really appreciate for your time, I use data- prefix , it works, all warning disappear. but I decide to keep it warning, I don't want my file to be strictly valid.I just want to ensure if i'm forget to do something